# Create virtual environment and activate it and then open command window inside that activated virtual environment

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenv

Writing a simple python script to automate creating and activating a virtual environment that then opens the command prompt and leaves it open inside that virtual environment so that the user can then add commands.

I have looked at `subprocess.call` and have been able to successfully create the virtual environment in the desired directory but I now can't get command prompt to open and stay open with that active virtual environment.

I have also looked at subprocess `Popen` but this is my first python script program and I am lost with it. Code is below:

```py
import subprocess

def main():
    subprocess.call('python -m venv virtual.env')
    subprocess.call('.\virtual.env\Scripts\activate.bat', shell=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trick you're looking for is `cmd.exe /k`

```
import subprocess

def main():
    subprocess.call('python -m venv virtual.env')
    subprocess.call('cmd.exe /k virtual.env\Scripts\activate.bat')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually really helped.

Comment: Hi @Raymond if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @KyleWillmon I'm looking for a solution to achieve the same goal under linux. Could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @Joey Any solution for Linux is going to depend on what terminal emulator is being used. And as can be seen [in the answers to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32547/how-to-launch-an-application-with-default-terminal-emulator-on-ubuntu), opening the "default" terminal emulator is currently not trivial. You should consider posting a new question (with some more detail about what terminal emulator you want to use). And that new question would likely belong on [the Unix and Linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)